# Make a list of Flutter Firebase field

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hi, I want to make a list inside the Flutter Firebase field. I'm creating an id for followers in the Field. In Firebase, there is a collection, user ID and followers id in the field. My encodings are as follows. But I'm not making a list. What are the changes I will make?

Followers_card

```
class FollowersCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final snap;

  const FollowersCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.snap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FollowersCard> createState() => _FollowersCardState();
}

class _FollowersCardState extends State<FollowersCard> {
  List<dynamic> followersList = []; // shouldn't use dynamic

  getdata() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) async {
      // get followerIds
      List<String> follwerIds = List.from(value.data()!['followers']);
      // loop through all ids and get associated user object by userID/followerID
      for (int i = 0; i < follwerIds.length; i++) {
        var followerId = follwerIds[i];
        var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .doc(followerId)
            .get();

        // push that data into followersList variable as we are going
        // to use that in listViewBuilder
        followersList.add(data);
      }
      setState(() {});
    });

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      getdata();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // use the listView builder to render the list of followers card
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: followersList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var followerItem = followersList[index];
            print('photoUrl');

            return _buildFollowersCard(
                followerItem['photoUrl'], followerItem['username']);
          }),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFollowersCard(String photoUrl, String username) {
    return Container(
      height: 70,
      width: double.infinity,
      color: mobileBackgroundColor,
      child: Card(
        child: Column(children: [
          //Header
          Container(
            height: 40,
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 4,
              horizontal: 16,
            ).copyWith(right: 0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 16,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    photoUrl,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          username,
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

followers_screen

```
class FollowersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FollowersScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FollowersScreen> createState() => _FollowersScreenState();
}

class _FollowersScreenState extends State<FollowersScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Image.asset(
          'Resim/logo.png',
          height: 50,
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
        builder: (context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => FollowersCard(
              snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `_FollowersScreenState.initState` is in the wrong place. It's inside the function `getdata` that it is trying to call. The `initState` is never called. That's why there is no list being built.

Also, `setState` is the one that assigns `State` values. So first, populate a temporary list of followers and then assign it to the `State` one inside the `setState` callback.

Below is the fixed snippet code for `_FollowersScreenState`:

```dart
class _FollowersCardState extends State<FollowersCard> {
  List<dynamic> followersList = []; // shouldn't use dynamic

  getdata() async {
    List<dynamic> followers = [];

    final currentUserSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get();

    // get followerIds
    List<String> follwerIds =
        List.from(currentUserSnapshot.data()!['followers']);
    // loop through all ids and get associated user object by userID/followerID
    for (int i = 0; i < follwerIds.length; i++) {
      var followerId = follwerIds[i];
      var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(followerId)
          .get();

      // push that data into the temp list variable as we are going
      // to use that in to setState
      followers.add(data);
    }
    setState(() => followersList = followers);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getdata();
  }

  ...
```

Comment: Undefined name 'followersList'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name, and Missing concrete implementation of 'State.build'.
Try implementing the missing method, or make the class abstract. i got the error

Comment: `followersList` is defined right below the `_FollowersCardState` class. Did you remove it unintentionally?

Comment: No, just below as you posted

Comment: I've added the head of `_FollowersCardState` to the answer. Please compare it to the one you have.

Comment: I found the solution to the error. But this time it also lists 5 from the same user.